# Cannot find file exported from python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, export

I have a problem with finding files I exported and saved in Python. Here are the methods I tried:
The data frame does exist and I have worked on it before trying to export it. Data frame name: `calc_frame`.

First method:

```
 calc_frame.to_csv(r'D:\Studia\Semestr 5\LabFiz2\Ćw7 9.10.2019\Pliki do sprawka\\ogólna.csv')
```

Second method:

```
testexcel = pd.ExcelWriter('D:\Studia\Semestr 5\LabFiz2\Ćw7 9.10.2019\Pliki do sprawka\ogólna.xlsx', engine = "xlsxwriter")
calc_frame.to_excel(testexcel, sheet_name = "test1")
testexcel.save()
```

And I still cannot find this file in that directory. However, when I do this:

```
 file_empty = open(r'D:\Studia\Semestr 5\LabFiz2\Ćw7 9.10.2019\Pliki do sprawka\\ogólna.csv')

 test_frame = pd.read_csv(file_empty, encoding='utf-8', sep=";")

 file_empty.close()

 test_frame.head()
```

Frame shows up, although a bit distorted (python doesn't recognize commas as separators).

I have no idea what to do at this point. I need help.

Comment: Please put your paths through `os.path.normpath` and see what it returns.

Comment: I typed: os.path.normpath(r'D:\Studia\Semestr 5\LabFiz2\Ćw7 9.10.2019\Pliki do sprawka\\ogólna.csv') and it returned given path

Comment: Ok, what does `os.path.isfile` return? Or `os.path.exists`?

Comment: os.path.exists(r'D:\Studia\Semestr 5\LabFiz2\Ćw7 9.10.2019\Pliki do sprawka\\ogólna.csv') returns True

Comment: The directory exists? Can you try without the double backslash before the filename?

Comment: Directory exists. I have other files in it. One backslash didn't make a difference